# How to join JSON to update multiple rows by primary key

Tags: sql-server, join

I am trying to update a log with JSON in SQL Server 2017. I can update a data point with `json_value`, which covers a few cases, but would ultimately like to join in incoming JSON.

Sample table:

```
key | col_1                         | col_2         | col_3
----+-------------------------------+---------------|-----------------
1   | json.lines[0].data.meta.data  | json.lines[0] | json.header.note
2   | json.lines[1].data.meta.data} | json.lines[1] | json.header.note
3   | json.lines[2].data.meta.data} | json.lines[2] | json.header.note
```

I'd like to update a single property in `col_1` and update `col_2` with an object as as as string.

Sample JSON:

```
declare @json nvarchar(max) = '[{
  header: {
      note: 'some note'
  }, lines: [{
     data {
       id: {
         key: 0,
         name: 'item_1'
       },
       meta: {
         data: 'item_1_data'
       }
     }, {...}, {...}
  }]
}]'
```

Query:

```
update logTable set 
col_1 = json_value(@json,'$.lines[__index__].data.meta.data'), -- what would the syntax for __index__ be?
col_2 = j.lines[key], -- pseudo code
col_3 = json_value(@json, '$'.header.note')

inner join openjson(@json) j
  on json_value(@json,'$.line[?].id.key') = logTable..key -- ? denotes indices that I'd like to iterate = join over
```

Expected Output:

```
key | col_1         | col_2                      | col_3
----+---------------+----------------------------|---------
1   | 'item_1_data' | 'data: { id: { key: 0...}' | '{header: { note: ...} }'
2   | 'item_2_data' | 'data: { id: { key: 1...}' | '{header: { note: ...} }'
3   | 'item_3_data' | 'data: { id: { key: 2...}' | '{header: { note: ...} }'
```

I'm not sure how to handle iterating over the `$.line` indices, but think a join would solve this if properly implemented.

How can I join to arrays of objects to update SQL rows by primary key?

Comment: `logTable` is probbaly your sample table and can you post full sample for your `line[]` JSON array? Thanks.

Comment: I've added more detail, but the actual object is quite large...

Comment: still is not clear what you want to do -- you have to give a full sample data AND the results you expect.  What should the output look like.

Comment: @Hogan OK... is this clearer with the updated table?

Comment: That is the actual contents of the data?  What is your expected output?

Comment: @Hogan an expected output section has been added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Original answer:**

You may try to parse your `JSON` using `OPENJSON` with [explicit schema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#return-value) (note, that your `JSON` is not valid):

Table and JSON:

```
CREATE TABLE #Data (
   [key] int,
   col_1 nvarchar(100),
   col_2 nvarchar(max)
)
INSERT INTO #Data
   ([key], [col_1], [col_2])
VALUES
   (1, N'', N''),
   (2, N'', N''),
   (3, N'', N'')

DECLARE @json nvarchar(max) = N'[{
   "lines": [
      {
      "data": {
          "id": {
             "key": 1,
             "name": "item_1"
          },
          "meta": {
             "data": "item_1_data"
          }
      }
     },
     {
     "data": {
          "id": {
             "key": 2,
             "name": "item_2"
          },
          "meta": {
             "data": "item_2_data"
          }
     }
     },
     {
     "data": {
          "id": {
             "key": 3,
             "name": "item_3"
          },
          "meta": {
             "data": "item_3_data"
          }
     }
     }
   ]
}]'
```

Statement:

```
UPDATE #Data
SET  
   col_1 = j.metadata,
   col_2 = j.data
FROM #Data
INNER JOIN (   
   SELECT *
   FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$[0].lines') WITH (
      [key] int '$.data.id.key',
      metadata nvarchar(100) '$.data.meta.data',
      data nvarchar(max) '$' AS JSON
   )
) j ON #Data.[key] = j.[key]
```

**Update:**

`Header` is common for all rows, so use `JSON_QUERY()` to update the table:

Table and JSON:

```
CREATE TABLE #Data (
   [key] int,
   col_1 nvarchar(100),
   col_2 nvarchar(max),
   col_3 nvarchar(max)
)
INSERT INTO #Data
   ([key], col_1, col_2, col_3)
VALUES
   (1, N'', N'', N''),
   (2, N'', N'', N''),
   (3, N'', N'', N'')

DECLARE @json nvarchar(max) = N'[{
   "header": {
     "note": "some note"
   },
   "lines": [
      {
      "data": {
          "id": {
             "key": 1,
             "name": "item_1"
          },
          "meta": {
             "data": "item_1_data"
          }
      }
     },
     {
     "data": {
          "id": {
             "key": 2,
             "name": "item_2"
          },
          "meta": {
             "data": "item_2_data"
          }
     }
     },
     {
     "data": {
          "id": {
             "key": 3,
             "name": "item_3"
          },
          "meta": {
             "data": "item_3_data"
          }
     }
     }
   ]
}]'
```

Statement:

```
UPDATE #Data
SET  
   col_1 = j.metadata,
   col_2 = j.data,
   col_3 = JSON_QUERY(@json, '$[0].header')
FROM #Data
INNER JOIN (   
   SELECT *
   FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$[0].lines') WITH (
      [key] int '$.data.id.key',
      metadata nvarchar(100) '$.data.meta.data',
      data nvarchar(max) '$' AS JSON
   )
) j ON #Data.[key] = j.[key]
```

Comment: OK! This is really good! I forgot a case when getting the header data as well though...

Comment: Awesome. This is perfect. Thank you!! :)